# How can I show a variable in a dialog box

Tags: scripts, dialog

```
$value = V 
dialog --title "Message" --msgbox '(here the data stored in a variable value must be displayed' 10 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the code below

```
value="V"
dialog --title "Message" --msgbox "your value: $value" 10 20
```

In the first line you declares a variable with the name `value` and the content `V`. Note, that there are no spaces around `=` and no dollar sign before the variable name.

In the second line, you shows the variable in a message box. To access the content of the variable, you need the dollar sign here.

---

And here is the solution as I understand you question before my edit **;)**

```
RESULT=$(dialog --inputbox "Enter a Line, please" 10 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-); echo "result: ${RESULT}"
```

In the example standard out and error out is written to a variable `3` and transferred from there to the `RESULT` variable. These can then be easily processed in the program.

`3>&` – clears the variable `3`.